# Auto-extending plot ranges - with interpolated data series

Tags: microsoft-excel

This site here explains of how to use *defined names* to auto-update the plot ranges, if you have a sheet with some data series, and a chart displaying those series, and then you want to add data and not adapt a dozen data ranges or so in the chart manually.

[Creating automatically extended plot ranges](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/creating_automatically_extended_plot_ranges.html)

I tried it, and it basically works, in Excel as in Office 365 MSO (16.0. ...).
There's one caveat: Some of my data series have some empty cells in between and set to interpolate between them. The reason for that is that there is one time axis, and several data series from different sources, some of which do not produce a data point as often as others, and I have no control over that.

And the formula from the article does not work with interpolated series. Which is to say, it seems not to be auto-selecting the full range, but only the first value plus a couple empty cells after that, rather random seeming (because there are more empty cells to the next value, which are not within the selection as I saw it)

So my question is: (how) can this auto-updating of ranges be made working also with interpolated series?

Comment: I found an article may be helpful to the question: [Plot Blank Cells and #N/A in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/plot-blank-cells-na-in-excel-charts/).

Comment: replacing the empty cells with #N/A indeed seems to do the trick here, as the range detection then works, thanks!